# Permission denied Paperclip and s3 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a rails 4 app deployed on heroku. I'm using Amazon s3 bucket to host images (using paperclip gem), but when I try to upload an image to my articles controller i get this error:

```
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /articles
```

I have gone through the steps listed [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#define-the-file-attribute-in-the-model). As i understand this could be a folder permission issue, but not really to sure how to tackle the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the following code in your */config/environments/production.rb* file and update ENV secret key names accordingly. The host name is dependent on your region, *us-west-1*, *eu-west-1*, etc.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com'
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the :s3_host_name did it for me. Cheers. I had it in an initialiser as other tuts have stated.